# Probability Density Function using the standard library?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stl, probability-density

Being able to use the `std <random>` to generate random numbers of different prob distributions is great... Now, *Is there any way to compute the probability of a set of numbers given a distribution and its parameters **using the standard library**?*

I am aware that I can code the Probability Density & Mass Functions for whatever distributions on my own (see example below for a single random variable), but I'd rather use the standard library if I could.

```
long double exponential_pdf(long double x, long double rate) {

    if ( x < 0.0 ) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    if ( rate < 0.0 ) {
        return NOT_A_NUMBER;
    }
    auto    pdf = rate * exp( - rate * x);
    return  pdf;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. :-( I have banged against that wall too.

Comment: @masaers I consider Boost as a "pre-Standard" library (see my answer below), but it depends on the OP if he considers that as an acceptable substitute.

Comment: @TemplateRex Parts of Boost (including the distributions) certainly is a pre-standard library, but adding a dependency on Boost to your project is not necessarily an option when you're "working for the man".

Comment: By the way, do you know if the pdf function in Boost takes the standard's distributions as parameters?

Comment: unfortunately, no, if you `#include <random>` and put `std::exponential_distribution`, you get an error "note:   ‘std::exponential_distribution<>’ is not derived from ‘const boost::math::exponential_distribution<RealType, Policy>’"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since C++11, the Standard Library contains a bunch of distributions that can be used for random number generation. Unfortunately, there is no functionality for computing probability densities, cumulative distributions or quantile functions in the Standard Library.

As for a rationale why this was not included in the Standard Library, see the [**working paper N1398**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1398.html) (emphasis mine)

> Some libraries provide the probability density function of a given
>   distribution as part of that distribution's interface. While this may
>   be useful occasionally, this proposal does not provide for such a
>   feature. One reason is separation of concerns: The distribution class
>   templates might benefit from precomputing large tables of values
>   depending on the distribution parameters, while the computation of the
>   probability density function does not. **Also, the function
>   representation is often straightforward, so the user can easily code
>   it himself.**

I don't quite agree with this reasoning: while it is true that the density functions are easy enough to code, the same does not hold for the cumulative distribution or quantile functions.

As a workaround, you could go to the [**Boost Math Toolkit**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/math/doc/html/index.html). It uses the same names as the Standard Library for the distributions, but allows you to compute `pdf()` and many more properties for these distributions. Boost libraries often find their way into the Standard, and if not, they are at least platform independent and widely available. Your example would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/distributions/exponential.hpp>

using namespace boost::math;

int main() 
{
    auto const lambda = 1.0;
    auto d = exponential_distribution<>{lambda};
    std::cout << pdf(d, 0) << "\n"; // exp(0) = 1
    std::cout << pdf(d, 1) << "\n"; // exp(-1) = 0.367879
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb7fbfa3a9abad57).

Comment: great answer! states why it is not possible to use std and offers a good alternative. thx

Comment: @dudu tnx, glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you are using C++17 already, there is a useful opensouce library [RandLib](https://github.com/Quanteeks/RandLib). In your example you could just write

```
#include “RandLib.h”

void main() {
    double lambda = 1;
    ExponentialRand X(lambda);
    X.f(0); //=1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@dudu

I do not know which compiler you are using, but bear in mind that  Microsoft Visual C++ compiler does not support long double primitive type.
Such a support will force compiler to emit x87  floating point code.

Comment: MSVC totally supports `long double`. It just happens to be the same as `double`.  Just like `long` happens to be the same as `int`.